# Error 'No such file or directory' when use click

Tags: python-3.x, path, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm using click 8.1.3 to parse my command,and my cli.py is like this:

```
@click.option('--output_dir', default=os.curdir, help='when outdated is true,choose directory which you want to put your cache file')
@click.option('--cache_dir', default=os.curdir, help='when outdated if false,choose directory where put cache file')
def main(outdated, nodes_path, river_path, cur_sta, up_sta, cutoff, upstream, downstream, cache_dir, output_dir):
……
```

But when I try to read cache files from a directory such as `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\test-cache`, it occured wrong:

```
PS C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\test_cache2> calcstream --nodes_path XXX --river_path YYY --cur_sta 0 --up_sta 10 --cache_dir C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\test-cache --outdated False
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Python310\Scripts\calcstream.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1130, in __call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\dijkstra_conda\cli.py", line 35, in main
upstream_node_on_mainstream(nodes_reader, network_reader, cur_sta, up_sta, outdated, cache_dir, output_dir)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\dijkstra_conda\dfs_path_test.py", line 463, in upstream_node_on_mainstream
origin_graph = get_upstream_stations_graph(node_reader, network_reader, number_src, outdated)[2]
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\dijkstra_conda\dfs_path_test.py", line 348, in get_upstream_stations_graph
upstream_graph = get_upstream_stations(node_reader, network_reader, number, outdated, cutoff, cache_dir, output_path)[0]
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\dijkstra_conda\dfs_path_test.py", line 243, in get_upstream_stations
stations_graph = build_graph(node_reader, network_reader, outdated, cache_dir, output_path)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\dijkstra_conda\dfs_path_test.py", line 205, in build_graph
nearest_point_line_dict = tie_outside_node(node_reader, network_reader, outdated, cache_dir, output_path)[1]
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\dijkstra_conda\dfs_path_test.py", line 115, in tie_outside_node
source_point_frame = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(cache_dir, 'source_project_points.csv'))
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 317, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 950, in read_csv
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 605, in _read
parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1442, in __init__
self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1729, in _make_engine
self.handles = get_handle(
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 857, in get_handle
handle = open(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\\source_project_points.csv'
```

It seems that the program still uses `os.curdir`(C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\test_cache2) to find `source_project_points.csv`, and I'm sure `source_project_points.csv` is in `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\test-cache`, so how to solve the problem?

[This](https://github.com/iHeadWater/station-simulator/tree/master/dijkstra_conda) is my project link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know, you shouldn't set default parameter in business code, rather write in `@click.option(default=)`.